# Is there any command line alternative to Activity Monitor that would yield the same results?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

I know there's `top` and `htop` commands, but they lack a lot of information. For example there is no way to list processes from Energy tab. Or is there at least some kind of API for Activity Monitor which could be used to develop the desired command line tool?

Answer (score 2):

A good reference giving insight on the energy tab is given [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2015/08/26/what-does-the-os-x-activity-monitors-energy-impact-actually-measure/).  It relates it to the Power column of the top command which you can generate by using top command as such: `top -stats pid,command,cpu,idlew,power -o power -d`  The power column is not usually displayed due to width of monitor.

Comment: I've read that before. As I said I know there is top - and it's absolutely not enough. This gives you current power usage but doesn't say if it's because of high perf gpu request or not. I would doubt also in accuracy as thread requiring high perf gpu is often not at the top yet battery drains much faster. But maybe it's because you get a snapshot of current energy usage every second - if somehow this could be accumulated per second or better per minute - then maybe it would push problematic pid at the top of the list. Activity Monitor has a variable saying if thread requires high gpu or not.

Comment: Or in short, activity monitor has plenty more data than top or htop.

Comment: No, activity monitor has same data as top or htop but it creates combinations of some of the info into new catagories.  Not new data but just a combination ofinfo.

Comment: Well, then how to get "high perf gpu" column in top? Or "App Nap" or "Preventing sleep"?

Comment: How is the high perf gpu column defined. It has no units. What does it even mean?  It was determined using the info obtained from some unix command. Probably top. Using an unknown equation tocombine certain columns of a top output. When they didn't give an expression or definintion for a value its hard totell.

Comment: If you read my lined article you would see that many of these parameters are just calculated using values obtained from top and some constants. it turned out that Power variable from top was identicle to Energy value from Activity monitor. Maybe Activity monitor combines top output to output from another command line tool. With no definintion of these vvariables its hard to tell. Apple doesn't make known how they are calculated.

Comment: You may not like my answer but I'd use caution in assuming Activity Monitor has more information than can be obtained using a few unix commands.  Maybe activity monitor does the arithematic for you but they don't say.

Comment: Top doesn't provide information I'm asking for. You assume I should be fine with top but top doesn't provide that info so how is that correct answer?

Comment: It's not. I understand and agree with what you are saying.  Top doesn't provide what you want and hence the info must be availabe elsewhere.  Activity Monitor is the easiest answer but hard to extract using command line. The point I was trying to make is that another unix command, besides top, may have the data you are looking for. But its hard to tell since a definition for the parameter is not given.  The actual data may not be generated anywhere but  is calculated in activity monitor.  I wasn't trying to say my answer was correct and I'm sorry if my comments came off like that.